# Remove a hover effect from the navigation

Tags: navigation, hover

Trying to remove the black "lines" (that appear when hovering over the items in my navigation bar). I think it's a feature built into the theme but i'm not sure how to get rid of them. I don't want ANY hover effect. website is [www.acclaim-lighting.com](http://www.acclaim-lighting.com). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you know basics of HTML and CSS

I think you should check in the **nav** or maybe **li** in the CSS portion and modify the part having the hover attribute.
like this:

```
li:hover {
  color: black
}
```

The above command means that the Text of the **li** (list) element text will become black on hovering.

By just commenting that "color: black" section by using "Double Forward Slash" **//** on the beginning of the line then the text color won't change.

So to be precise do comment on that section which has **:hover** attribute and contains **black**.

Do a little bit Hit and Trial and you will Fix it.